# android - keep google map fragment zoomed in on location when leaving app

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location

I have a location service which runs in the background and updates the location of the user in the fragment.

When closing the app, the service comes to the foreground with `startForeground()` and showing an ongoing notification.

When I click the notification, it opens the app, but what I want to change is that the map is all zoomed out, and I have to wait for the next location updated to zoom in the map.

my `Fragment`'s `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, root);

    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            startLocationService();

        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

So this method is called everytime the fragment is created - for example, the scenario of:

Open app, `onCreateView` called, location service starts, zoom in map, closing app (service still running and showing notification), notification click, then `onCreateView` called again and map is zoomed out at first.

Is there a good way to "keep" the user location and prevent from the map to do the whole zoomed-out -> wait for location update -> zoom in?

I want that when the user opens the app from notification click, the map is already zoomed in on his location.

Comment: How about to store the user location while exiting the app in sharedprefence and onMapReady set that location and add zoom level without animating camera

Comment: hey. by animating  you mean this? 
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(currentLatLng).zoom(15).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

How can I zoom in without animating the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow this steps :

1) Saved your last location and zoom level using SharedPreference

2) Get the old Location and zoom level on your OnCreateView method from SharedPreference

3) Call the first statement in onMapReady() callback without animating camera :

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(oldLocation.getLatitude(), oldLocation.getLongitude()), 12(yourzoomlevel)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I fixed it almost 90% by following

1. use fused location
2. save the location in share-preferences
3. broadcast from Location Service when first time location is found so the camera          of map is moved to that location instantly
4. remove the animation from camera zoom-in

**use this code for camera move**

```js
 CameraUpdate center=
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(40.76793169992044,
                                                 -73.98180484771729));
    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

    map.moveCamera(center);
    map.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what do you mean by "remove the animation from camera zoom-in"? I have to do
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(currentLatLng).zoom(15).build(); with the zoom at least once, becauseotherwise the camera is far away. Did you mean doing it only one time?